# Material Design Flat Tree - Changing state of property node.expanded but tree does not refresh

Tags: angular, angular-material, tree

My project is built with Angular 17.00 and Angular/material 17.00. The issue I'm facing is that the tree is only partly updating after adding a new child node to an existing none-expandable node. Visually the tree shows the new node add with correct indentation but the expand/collapse icon is absent from the parent node even though the parent expandable property is set true when the new node is added.

This is what it looks like:
[image: screenshots]

I would have expected the expand/collapse icon to display after:

```js
this.dataSource.data = this.treeControl.dataNodes;
```

Also I tried to force a change detection with:

```js
// Manually trigger change detection cdr injected in constructor(cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) 
this.cdr.detectChanges();
```

Any suggestions would be most welcome as currently I'm stumped.
Thank you for reading and any help.

The insert typescript code:

```js
    /**
     * Insert a new node relative to active node
     * @param p: 0 above; 1 below; -1 into and and make active node expandable
     */
    newNode(p:number) {
        if (this.active.node) {
            let i = this.active.index;
            let lev = this.active.node.level;
            if(p < 0) {
                p = 1;
                lev++;
                this.active.node.expandable = true;
            }
            i += p;
            const node: KKFlatNode = {
                label: 'New Node',
                level: lev,
                expandable: false,
                data: Date.now(), //fixme:
            };
            this.insertNodeAt(node, i);
            // Manually trigger change detection cdr injected in constructor(cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) 
            this.cdr.detectChanges();
        }
    }


    // Insert a new node
    insertNodeAt(node: KKFlatNode, index: number, asChild: boolean = false): void {
        node = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(node))
        console.log('insertNodeAt:', node, ' indx:', index);
        // Insert the new node at the specified index
        this.treeControl.dataNodes.splice(index, 0, node);
        // Update the data source and tree control
        this.dataSource.data = this.treeControl.dataNodes;
    }
```

Tree markup:

```html
<div class="mat-tree-container">
    <mat-tree [dataSource]="dataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl">
        <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node" matTreeNodePadding matTreeNodePaddingIndent="15" (click)="onNode(node)"
            [ngClass]="{ 'active-node': active.node === node }">
            <!-- use a disabled button to provide padding for tree leaf -->
            <button mat-icon-button disabled></button>
            {{node.label}}
        </mat-tree-node>
        <!-- This is the tree node template for expandable nodes -->
        <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node;when: hasChild" matTreeNodePadding matTreeNodePaddingIndent="15" (click)="onNode(node)"
            [ngClass]="{ 'active-node': active.node === node }">
            <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle [attr.aria-label]="'Toggle ' + node.label">
                <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror" style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">
                    {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
                </mat-icon>
            </button>
            {{node.label}}
        </mat-tree-node>
    </mat-tree>
</div>
```